# Set background/opaque to all JLabels

Tags: java, swing, label, apply

See my code:

```
package hsleiden.webcat.exercise12_08;

import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

public class newFrame extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args){

    newFrame frame = new newFrame();

    frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,3));
    frame.setSize(200, 200);
    frame.setTitle("Opdracht 12.8");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public newFrame(){
        JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Black", JLabel.CENTER);
        JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Blue", JLabel.CENTER);
        JLabel label3 = new JLabel("Cyan", JLabel.CENTER);
        JLabel label4 = new JLabel("Green", JLabel.CENTER);
        JLabel label5 = new JLabel("Magenta", JLabel.CENTER);
        JLabel label6 = new JLabel("Orange", JLabel.CENTER);

        Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.YELLOW);

        label1.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        label2.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        label3.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        label4.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        label5.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        label6.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        label1.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        label2.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        label3.setForeground(Color.CYAN);
        label4.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
        label5.setForeground(Color.MAGENTA);
        label6.setForeground(Color.ORANGE);

        label1.setBorder(border);
        label2.setBorder(border);
        label3.setBorder(border);
        label4.setBorder(border);
        label5.setBorder(border);
        label6.setBorder(border);

        label1.setOpaque(true);
        label2.setOpaque(true);
        label3.setOpaque(true);
        label4.setOpaque(true);
        label5.setOpaque(true);
        label6.setOpaque(true);


        add(label1);
        add(label2);
        add(label3);
        add(label4);
        add(label5);
        add(label6);

    }
}
```

As you can see its very troublesome to apply background, border, opaque per label.. thats 18 lines for 1 and the same thing. I was wondering if someone could tell me how I can apply all the things (background, opaque, border) to all labels without having to do it per label. Since they are all the same(except foreground).

Hope someone has a solution for me.

Thanks!

Comment: There are many good answers below that have addressed your question. You may accept one of them if you feel it answers your question. You may ask for more info if you think they don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can create your own class that extends JLabel and implements Clonable. You can override the clone method and create as many copies of a JLabel as you want.
2. Spring provides a handy way of doing this with BeanUtils.copyProperties

Answer (score 3):

You can create method for creating and adding a new `JLabel` like next:

```
private void addNewLbl(String text, Color foreground){
    JLabel lbl = new JLabel(text, JLabel.CENTER);
    lbl.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.YELLOW));
    lbl.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    lbl.setForeground(foreground);
    lbl.setOpaque(true);
    add(lbl);
}
```

And use it in construction your `JFrame`: `addNewLbl("black",Color.BLACK);`

Answer (score 2):

Use an array of labels instead and call `setBackground` for every element in the array referencing a `Color` array to get the title & colors for corresponding components.

Comment: hmm I see, but then I'd have to create an array and set the background etc per array index which kinda still makes me have to type all the lines per label. Or could you show an example of what you mean?